# Hide Column on Crystal Reports VS 2010 at Runtime

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I'm trying to make a column invisible in the Crystal Reports using Visual Studio 2010 at runtime, but I've found nothing helpfull in the net.
The best answer I found is about an old API called craxdrt.dll which I can't import the dll to my project.
I also have found code in VB speaking about some Suppress property in the FieldObject or ReportObject class, but there is nothing like that in the Crystal Report Version running on VS 2010.
Someone knows how can I make it without using the designer nor formulas?

edit:
I'm searching something like this:
`report.ReportDefinition.Sections[3].ReportObjects[0].Suppress = true;`

Comment: There are approximately a bajillion million versions of Crystal Reports.  A few things then - which version are you using precisely?  Have you tried contacting their support or looking at the docs?

Comment: I don't know exactaly, in VS help menu it shows this: Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0
I downloaded the plugin a couple months ago directly from the SAP site, so a think it is the last version.

Comment: edit: the version is 13.0.1.220

Comment: Is that line of code an almost-working line of code, or just representing the bit of API you're looking for?

Comment: Honestly I don't understand why you're trying to do this without the designer or formulas. Maybe it would be easier to change your database query so that, in this case, it provides nulls in that column instead.

Comment: It's not a working code. To the second question, I'm trying to do a report with autosize columns and dynamically choose which column will be displayed and which not. And I'm trying to do this without need to change the report design. I'm not using sql, I'm using .NET Objects. The reason to not use formulas is to make it the most generic to use I can. I think this feature is very usefull